# has_many IF conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have Advertisements which can have ladyies, but only if the type is a "club".

Is there a rails-way to do that? especially with not creating lady objects?
Do I have to check a lady object, before creating, if her parent is type=club?

```
class Advertisement < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_inclusion_of :type, in: %w(club lady)

  has_many :ladies, :dependent=>:destroy

  #only have ladies if the club =
  def ladies 
    return nil unless type == "club"
    super    
  end

end
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rails way to do that is STI:

```
 class Advertisement < ActiveRecord::Base
 end

 class LadyAd < Advertisement
   has_many :ladies, :dependent=>:destroy
 end
```

And only LadyAd object able to have ladies.

Comment: that is the same way like before.
before we had Clubs and SingleLadies, the only difference was, that a club can have a lot of ladys and a singlelady ist just herself.

but i want to switch to just one Advertisement, cuz Lady or Club have 1:1 the same attributes, with just the difference, that a club can have many working girls, and a Lady ist just working alone

Comment: I don't get it. Advertisement was Club & Lady before ? Do you have seperate models that inherit from Advertisment. Are you making self referential join when you do has_many :ladies ? Or is Lady a seperate model (no pun intended) with her own table ?

Comment: its a little chaos with the names.
now i have Club and SingleLady. Both are 100% the same, same pictures, same attrivbutes, with the difference, that a Club can have many Ladies (which is a complete other model).

In a city i have to look for clubs AND singleladys and if i change one thing, change both etc. its not DRY.

i want summartie it to Advertisement, and Advertisement can have ladies, if its a club. its also helpful for my users, i am providing an API and they can insert easiert advertisements.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using active record association extensions: (using proxy_association.owner)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions

```
module LadiesAtClub
  def at_club
    # you may need to iterate over an array or something here...
    proxy_association.owner.type == 'club'
  end
end

class Advertisement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ladies :extend => LadiesAtClub
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems all this is mixing composition (has_many) with inheritance (lady < advertisement) which doesn't make much sense (technically and conceptually). If this is the case and you are not using Lady and Club objects, you should at least rename the type to ad_type...

Assuming you're making a self referential join you'll then need a club_id column :

```
class Advertisement < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :ladies, -> {where(type: 'club')}, class_name: "Advertisment"
 end
```

Comment: currently i have Clubs and SingleLady. A Club is a club which can have a lot of ladys. A Singlelady has the same like a club, pictures, datas, opening_Times, just with the difference that she is alone and dont have any employees. So i have to look in the city for clubs and singleladies, which is just duplicated code. thats why i want to summarize it to Advertisement (which is a club or a singlelady) and it can have working_ladies if it is a club. hope you get it now :-)

Comment: Well I 'get' the problem and the goal but I dont know what tables to query on. If you are using STI (as the attribute type suggest), Advertisement, Club and SingleLady can all be on the same table. You should show your whole domain model to clear out the ambiguities before finding the good help...